# How to debug a Prolog program

Tags: debugging, prolog

I am sorry to bother you with this simple problem, but I have now spent 2 hours on this problem with no success. My biggest problem is that I do not know how to debug a Prolog program, which limits my ability to understand why this does not work. My question is, therefore, how I, with the help of some sort of debugger or helping tool, could figure out why this program does not give the expected results:

```
combinelists(L1|List1, L2|List2) :- 
    write(L1),
    write(L2),
    nl,
    combinelists(List1, List2).

printlist([L1|List]) :-
    write(L1), 
    nl,
    printlist(List).
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
1 ?- printlist([egg,egg2]).
egg
egg2
false.

2 ?- combinelists([egg,egg2],[egg3,egg4]).
false.
```

The output I was expecting in the last case was:
eggegg3
egg2egg4
false.

I tried turning on trace in SWI-prolog and got the following. This, however, did not answer why the output is empty. What kind of tools could have helped me out here. Also if you know the solution to this problem, I would also be most grateful!

```
[trace] 5 ?- combinelists([egg,egg2],[egg3,egg4]).
   Call: (6) combinelists([egg, egg2], [egg3, egg4]) ? creep
   Fail: (6) combinelists([egg, egg2], [egg3, egg4]) ? creep
false.

[trace] 6 ?- printlist([egg,egg2]).
   Call: (6) printlist([egg, egg2]) ? creep
   Call: (7) write(egg) ? creep
egg
   Exit: (7) write(egg) ? creep
   Call: (7) nl ? creep

   Exit: (7) nl ? creep
   Call: (7) printlist([egg2]) ? creep
   Call: (8) write(egg2) ? creep
egg2
   Exit: (8) write(egg2) ? creep
   Call: (8) nl ? creep

   Exit: (8) nl ? creep
   Call: (8) printlist([]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) printlist([]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) printlist([egg2]) ? creep
   Fail: (6) printlist([egg, egg2]) ? creep
false.

[trace] 7 ?- combinelists([egg,egg2],[egg3,egg4]).
   Call: (6) combinelists([egg, egg2], [egg3, egg4]) ? creep
   Fail: (6) combinelists([egg, egg2], [egg3, egg4]) ? creep
false.
```

Comment: In order to match a list with at least an element you should use `[H|T]` instead of `H|T`. In your first clause you missed the square brackets.

Comment: I love you, @TudorBerariu! Thank you so much! There is no way a debugger could have helped me figure out this.

Comment: If you want to understand Prolog, start with side effect free programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match a list with at least an element you should use `[H|T]` instead of `H|T`. In your first clause you missed the square brackets.
                    – Tudor Berariu